# Javascript Highcharts Mapping multiple values without showing them all in the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and currently getting 2 values but I need to get able to get some extra values without showing them in the chart.

Some first I'm getting the data:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: urlhere,
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {

        mainData = result;
        dataCount = (Object.keys(result.other).length);


    }
});
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
    "obj": [
        {
            "id": "223",
            "name": "Name here",
            "description": "Description Here"
        },
        "other": [
                {
                    "id": "5304",
                    "name": "Area 1",
                    "description": "This is area 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5305",
                    "name": "Area 2",
                    "description": "This is Area 2"
                }
            ],
    ]
}
```

Then I map the data:

```
var theData = mainData.other.map(function(e){
    return [e.id, dataCount];

});
```

Now on the chart click event I can get the e.id value but using this:

```
alert(event.point.name);
```

What I need to do is to also be able to get the name and description values but not show it in the chart itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a point to an object - it does not have to be an array.

```
var theData = mainData.other.map(function(e) {
  return {
    x: Number(e.id),
    y: dataCount,
    name: e.name,
    description: e.description
  };
});
```

Then your point will have all additional properties like description.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qRvn2/19/